# Car horn works only sometimes and with very very low sound

Tags: car, noise, horn

My car (Suzuki Mehran) horn works only sometimes after many days and with very low sound. The problem started when I turned on car ac about a month ago. In start the horn sound became low whenever car ac was on. 
But now even without ac, the car horn rarely works with a very low sound.

I don't think its battery problem because lights and other things work fine and the battery is new.

Comment: Try activating the horn, and if you hear the "low sound", aggressively turn the steering wheel back and forth and listen to see if the sound changes.  This should be done with the vehicle not moving, of course.  Do you press a stalk lever for the horn sound, or a part of the steering wheel?  I am not familiar with Pakastani vehicles.

Comment: The sound is very low at first but as I press the the steering 2,3 times the sound completely turns off

Answer (score 5):

Check to see how many volts the horn relay is sending to the horn. if it's less than ignition voltage at the horn either the relay is bad or you have a wiring problem. If you have ignition voltage at the horn make sure it's not touching anything and check for a good ground to the chassis. Otherwise replace the horn.

Also sometimes the switch in the steering wheel or the clockspring can go bad and may be sending a partial ground to the relay not allowing it to ground the horn relay coil.